# Postgres For rec in %variable%

Tags: postgresql, for-loop

I'd like on postgres to use variables in the SQL statement which is in a For Loop statement.

Something like this:

```
_sql=' select eventid from incidentappelsm order by date limit _time_minutes';

FOR rec IN  select _sql
        
    LOOP
        _output = _output || rec.eventid || ',' ;
        _Nb =_Nb+1;
    END LOOP;
```

It does not work. I can't find out how to make it work.

Comment: `for in execute ...`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING

Comment: Why not simply `array_to_string (array_agg (eventid), ',')`?